# Matrix entries field prevents following Matrix field to display

Tags: matrix

I've setup a Matrix field with an entries field and output the value like this:

```
{% set entry = block.blockLink.first() %}
 {% if entry %}
  <p class="ctaLink"><a href="{{ entry.url }}">Find out more</a></p>
 {% endif %}
```

This outputs the value of the entries field OK. However any other Matrix field that follows on from this one fails to display at all. What am I doing wrong? Any advice gratefully received!

Comment: After trial and error I came up with this alternative: `       {% if block.blockLink|length %}
        <p class="ctaLink"><a href="{{ block.blockLink.first.url }}">Find out more</a></p>
       {% endif %}`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I'm following, but would you mind adding what worked for you as an official answer?  Might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that the `entry` you are defining is confilicting with the `entry` that Craft gives you as the entry that this template is displaying. Try this, and see if it helps:

```
{% set blockLinkEntry = block.blockLink.first() %}
{% if blockLinkEntry %}
  <p class="ctaLink"><a href="{{ blockLinkEntry.url }}">Find out more</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this as the solution I used above was working. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error I came up with this alternative:

```
{% if block.blockLink|length %}
  <p class="ctaLink"><a href="{{ block.blockLink.first.url }}">Find out more</a</p>
{% endif %}
```

This worked for me, but I'm not sure if it's the 'correct' method or not.

Comment: Both cases you are avoiding overwriting the `entry` that Craft has set for you. Either one is correct.